# after ubuntu upgrate to 20.04. lenovo middle button stop working. how can enable again?

Tags: server, 20.04

IMAGE [lenovo thinkpad t470](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA76N.jpg)

not sure if below information is helpful

```
xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
dmesg |grep -i failed
[    0.299301] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    0.354184] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[    0.354189] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[    3.823359] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to program MOCS registers; expect performance issues.
[    3.934040] thermal thermal_zone2: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    5.159820] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[    5.159866] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[   15.184345] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-110)
```

Comment: What do you mean it stopped working ? like what it supposed to do? I'm asking because I also have a T470 Thinkpad, and maybe I can help with that.